# Conditional probability density of the sum of an uniform random variable with a constant

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I am interested in the conditional distribution of the sum of a uniform random variable and a constant.

Let $X = d + \epsilon_d$.

$d$ is the true measurement value.

$\epsilon_d$ is the error in the measurement such that $\epsilon_d \sim U(-0.5, 0.5)$.

$d + \epsilon_d > 0$.

How would one derive the conditional probability density $P(X|d)$?

Per comments below, sounds like I should reframe the question by setting constant $d$ to be a degenerate random variable:

Let $Y = d$, $X = \epsilon_d$, $Z = X + Y$.

What is the conditional density $P(Z | Y)$?

Per this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473790/conditional-density-of-sum-of-two-independent-and-continuous-random-variables), the conditional density of the sum of two random variables conditioned on one of the variables is:

$P_{Z|Y}(z) = P_{X}(z - y)$

Which implies:

$P_{X + Y}(d + \epsilon_d) = P_{X}(\epsilon_d) = 1$?

Comment: If $d$ is constant then you get $U(d-0.5,d+0.5)$ - so some of your text may be contradictory if $0 < d < 0.5$ and $-0.5 < \epsilon_d <-d$

Comment: Thanks @Henry edited.

Comment: A constant can be regarded as a degenerate random variable, and this random variable is independent of all other random variables.

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate edited per your comments.